# How cascading modifies original object?

Tags: dart

```dart
var intList = [3, 2, 1];
var sorted = intList..toList()..sort(); // [1, 2, 3]
var sorted2 = intList..toList().sort(); // [3, 2, 1]
```

Why my original list is also being modified in first sort and which list is being sorted in second sort?

**NOTE:** I'm not looking for the correct way to do it which is this:

```dart
var sorted = intList.toList()..sort(); // [1, 2, 3]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`x..y` evalutes to `x`. Cascade chains are evaluated left-to-right, so `x..y..z` is the same as `(x..y)..z`.  Your first example therefore makes calls to `toList()` and to `sort()` on the original object.

[Member access (`.`) has higher precedence than the cascade operator (`..`)](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#operators).  Your second example calls `sort()` on the copy returned by `toList()`, not on the original object.

Comment: Thanks, maybe I can understand it better if you can tell me what `intList..toList()` is returning; a copied list or the original list?

Comment: @iDecode As I said: `x..y` evaluates to `x`, so `intList..toList()` evaluates to `intList`, and the result of `toList()` is discarded.

Comment: @iDecode As I said, in the second example, `sort()` is called on the result of `toList()`, but the result of the cascade operator is always the left operand.